# PDO won't select HTML

Tags: php, sql, pdo

```
$username_decoded = '<i>marco</i>';
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE username=:username");
$stmt->bindParam(':username',$username_decoded,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

$all_fetched = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

print_r($all_fetched);
```

The code above gives me empty array. That username exists in the db. What's wrong with it?

Comment: You're absolutely certain the username `<i>marco</i>` exists in the database? (Also, do you have warnings turned on? Are there any?)

Comment: Does dropping the `WHERE` part return anything?

Comment: You are 100% sure the `<i>` stuff is not encoded, for example as HTML entities? `&lt;i&gt;`

Comment: Surprisingly, I can select $username_decoded using LIKE operator. :\

Comment: @minitech Yes. The whole table.

Comment: Would the type of the column happen to be `CHAR` and not `VARCHAR`?

Comment: Oopss... @Pekka Yes, you're correct. It is encoded. I thought I had it decoded already, sorry for wasting your time haha. It works nicely now.

Comment: @minitech sorry, my mistake lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm betting the type of the `username` column is `CHAR(n)` and not `VARCHAR(n)`. `CHAR(n)` adds spaces to the end of the string to pad it to fit the width of the column. Change your column to `VARCHAR(n)` and make sure to trim all of the excess spaces afterwards.

Otherwise, if you can't change the column, you can either use `str_pad($username_decoded, length of column)` before comparing it against the database, or use `TRIM(username)` in your query.

Comment: I'll be sure to keep this in mind. Might be useful for future projects.